# Qt4 'usleep' was not declared in this scope in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, qt4

I'm using **QtCreator 3.3.2** on **Ubuntu 14.04(i386)**, and **Qt4.8.6**.

The problem is just like what the title said and with a similar error:

> 'sleep' was not declared in this scope.

And these are headers included.

```
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDir>
#include <QDate>
#include <QTime>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QFile>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QtGlobal>
```

Weird thing is there were no problems when I used **Ubuntu 12.04** and `QtCreator2.4.1(Qt4.8.0);`

Comment: Try looking at man pages of sleep and usleep, they tell what headers you need.

Comment: Generally speaking, headers don't give any guarantees about which other headers they include, so error is probably because something changed in Qt or (more likely) GNU/Linux headers.

Comment: Thanks.  So I just replaced it with nanosleep, there're a lot of .so problems came out: `libm4play.so:-1: error: undefined reference to SDL_GetVideoSurface'` and `libm4play.so:-1: error: undefined reference to SDL_UnlockYUVOverlay'` and many similar errors for 38 in total. libm4play.so is a third-party lib. Have any idea about this? thanks! @hyde

Comment: Yes, but if you have another question, please ask another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `nanosleep` which is available in `#include <ctime>`.

Also you might need to include `unistd.h` for `sleep` and so on which I do not recommend.

All I can think of is that in your previous installation these files were auto included or macro'd.

[nanosleep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) or `man nanosleep`

Comment: Thanks. But after I replace it with nanosleep, there're a lot of .so problems came out: `libm4play.so:-1: error: undefined reference to `SDL_GetVideoSurface' ` and ` libm4play.so:-1: error: undefined reference to `SDL_UnlockYUVOverlay'` and many similar errors for 38 in total. _libm4play.so_ is a third-party lib. Have any idea about this? thanks!@deW1

Comment: @Henry Your errors shouldn't have anything to do with sleep rather than with the includes of the library. You can try to include `unistd.h` and use sleep to see if that works, but I guess the underlying errors were just not shown because the compiler stopped at the unreferenced sleep.

Comment: still doesn't work. I'd better switch to ubuntu 12.04. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Henry you should ask a new question about that as this one got answered. I doubt 12.04 got anything to do with that. Though you might need to recompile the library instead.